# R.Java not generating on any android project, even if it's new

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

R.Java not generating on any android project, even if it's new. "R cannot be resolved to a variable" 
I re-installed Eclipse, I created new projects. No matter what I do, it ALWAYS happens.
They are new files. That mean there are no errors in the .xml files. Clean build does nothing.

I have installed the android-sdk. I have created an android project. The project is set to build automatically

Comment: Have you tried compiling the project? R is generated by the compiler.

Comment: Have you installed the android-sdk?? And are you creating android-project or simple project?

Comment: I have installed the android-sdk. I have created an android project. The project is set to build automatically.

Comment: Please check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712580/r-java-file-just-went-missing/17713074#17713074

Comment: Check Run > Build automatically it checked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out the issue. What happened was that while there were no XML errors in MY projects, there were a few in a library I was using. That completely destroyed the R.Java's ability to autogenerate.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any Libs? Sometimes when they have errors, it screws your R.java up (I had this with ABS recently).

Comment: @NeedleBallista It must've been whilst I was reading the OP because only Russells answer was here when I typed it :p